# How to merge two matrix(DataFrame) with different row size and same column size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

Hi I just started with python and I came across on such problem. I loaded my dataset from *.csv*, then I saved only those candidates which column 0 value were equal to 3 or 5 in two different variables (lest call them `leafs_three`, `leafs_five`). Then I wanted to merge these `leafs_three`, `leafs_five` into one `leafs_three_and_five`, but actually I do not know how can I do it.

Sizes of the `leafs_three` and  `leafs_five`:

- `leafs_three` is a **[10 rows x 16 columns]** *matrix*
- `leafs_five` is a  **[12 rows x 16 columns]** *matrix*

Type of those matrices is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. What I want to achieve by merging `leafs_three` and  `leafs_five` is to get a **[22 rows x 16 columns]** *matrix*

What I tried:

```py
leafs_three_and_five = np.concatenate((leafs_three, leafs_five))
leafs_three_and_five = pd.merge(leafs_three, leafs_five)
```

As the result of np.concatenate I get the array of the arrays

As the result of pd.merge I get the empty DataFrame

Comment: [Refer to this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) and choose what you need to do. And your data is in `DataFrame`s not matrices. It seems you need `leafs_three_and_five = pd.concat([leafs_three, leafs_five])`

Comment: Yes I also found this solution but thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate matrices which you loaded with library ***pandas*** by `pd.read_csv` method you should use another method provided by ***pandas***. This method is `pd.concat` which take an array of DataFrame's which you want to merge. For example

```py
pd.concat([data_frame_a, data_frame_b])
```

To read more about this method visit this link: [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)